# Enable Alpha & Specular Color for textures through python

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

how would I go about using the script below to enable specular color and Alpha to all textures in a scene? I've tried various bpy.data.THING none have worked. Below is just the last thing I've tried before asking this.

```
for mat in bpy.data.MaterialTextureSlots:

    mat.use_map_color_spec = True
    mat.use_map_alpha = True
```

Answer (score 2):

To set [`MaterialTextureSlot.use_map_alpha`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.MaterialTextureSlot.html#bpy.types.MaterialTextureSlot.use_map_alpha) on all texture slots on all materials.
    import bpy

```
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    for ts in mat.texture_slots:
        if ts is not None:
            ts.use_map_alpha = True
            ts.use_map_color_spec = True
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is only working on one material's textures and then errors out, any ideas? 

also I had the spec color backwards it should be use_map_color_spec

Comment: whoops, forget to check for empty slot.